# Generic function to evaluate properties dynamically

Tags: c#

I have the following classes:

```
public class Vehicle
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool CanFly { get; set; }
    public bool CanDive { get; set; }
}

public class Hdd
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool CanRead { get; set; }
    public bool CanWrite { get; set; }
    public bool CanCopy { get; set; }
}
```

I want to write one function that can filter for example if a specific car exists (filter by firstOrDefault name) then check the given condition as parameter, for example CanFly or CanDive... etc

so i was thinking of:

```
public class TestProperties
{
    public bool Check<T>(List<T> items, string name,
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
    {
        var expr = (MemberExpression)expression.Body;
        var prop = (PropertyInfo)expression.Member;
        //1- Filter items with the given name
        // return false if no records found
        // return false if the condition fails 
    }
}
```

Then I would call the functions as follow

```
var myHdds= GetHdd();
var myCars= GetCars();
var CanRead = Check<Hdd>(myHdds,"samsung",x => x.CanRead);
var CanFly = Check<Vehicle>(myCars,"Audi",x => x.CanFly);
```

How can i implement the Check function?

Comment: You have your function types backwards.  It should be `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. Try this -

```
public bool Check<T>(List<T> items, Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
{
    return items.Any(x => expression.Compile()(x));
}
```

or,

```
public bool Check<T>(List<T> items, Func<T, bool> compiledExp)
{
    return items.Any(x => compiledExp(x));
}
```

and call like this -

```
Check<Vehicle>(myCars, x => x.Name == "Audi" && x.CanFly);
Check<Hdd>(myHdds,x => x.Name == "Samsung" &&  x.CanRead);
```

But now to think of this, you really don't need a method to do that. It is literally one line of code.

Personally I would have preferred an extension method -

```
public static bool Check<T>(this List<T> items, Func<T, bool> compiledExp)
{
    return items.Any(x => compiledExp(x));
}
```

and call like -

```
myHdds.Check(x => x.Name == "Samsung" &&  x.CanRead);
```

Comment: `.Any(x => compiledExp(x))` can just be `.Any(compiledExp)`.

But since that method just calls `Any`, why do you even need it in the first place

Comment: Yup. Good suggestion. But I guess I will keep as it is. Makes it more readable and yeah it does not make sense to have a method just to do that. But I guess OP might have other plans and this could be a simplified version. So just showing the idea.